# how do i load the swfs through http so that the client browser can cache them and communicate with the server-side over https?

Tags: apache-flex, caching, https

The client-side application is a Flex application and communicate with server-side java application using blazeds. As you know, most browsers don't cache SWFs loaded over https, but i want load the swfs through http so that the client browser can cache them and communicate with the server-side over https? How can i achieve that?

Comment: Interesting question and clever idea, though I expect it's not possible to do. (I'm not a Flash expert though).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without generating a prompt for the user to allow for this content to load in some browsers. Doing this in general violates security of the https session.

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with BlazeDS securely regardless of how the Flex SWF was loaded into the broswer. It's entirely possible to embed your SWF in a web page laoded over http, then for that Flex application to communicate with BlazeDS securely.

The key concern is with BlazeDS. How your Flex SWF is loaded into the browser isnt important.
Your Flex client needs to communicate with BlazeDS over a **SecureAMFChannel**. On the server side, you set up the Secure AMF channel to use either container based or custom authentication. The first time you use the channel, Blaze will send a response indicating the user needs to authenticate.

See this link for details. [BlazeDS Developer Guide](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=services_security_2.html)